# How to get array values without null : Retrofit Android

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

i'm using retrofit for service calls.it's return 5 data sets.each data set contain 6 values.each data set contain one actual values and others are null.how can get actual values without null values?

POST man response is like bellow

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "successfully count new orders",
    "data": [
        {
            "order_count": "3"
        },
        {
            "pending_order": "0"
        },
        {
            "schedule": "2017-11-18 12:00",
            "id_order": "272",
            "reference": "KB-838704"
        },
        {
            "deli_orders": "0"
        },
        {
            "store_count": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

Webservice call

```
 WebserviceAPI apiService =retrofit.create(WebserviceAPI.class);
            Call<OrderResponse> call = apiService.getSummery("countnew",token_acces);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<OrderResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<OrderResponse> call, Response<OrderResponse> response) {
                    OrderResponse result = response.body();
                    List<Order> data=result.getData();
                    status=result.isStatus();
                    msg= result.getMessage();

                    for (Order a:data)
                    {
                        try {
                            Log.d("ress",""+a.getOrder_count()+" : "+a.getPending_order()+" : "+a.getReference()
                            +" : "+a.getSchedule()+" : "+a.getDeli_orders()+" : "+a.getStore_count());

                        //update

                           if( !(a.getOrder_count().contentEquals("null"))){
                            Log.d("ress","new order "+a.getOrder_count());
                            //txtNewOrder.setText(a.getOrder_count());
                        }
                        if( !(a.getPending_order().contentEquals("null"))){
                            Log.d("ress","pending "+a.getPending_order());
                           // txtPendingOrder.setText(a.getPending_order());
                        }
                        if( !(a.getReference().contentEquals("null"))){
                            Log.d("ress","reference "+a.getReference());
                            //txtRecentOrder.setText(a.getReference());
                        }
                        if( !(a.getSchedule().contentEquals("null"))){
                            Log.d("ress","time "+a.getSchedule());
                            //txtRemainingTime.setText(a.getSchedule());
                        }
                        if( !(a.getDeli_orders().contentEquals("null"))){
                            Log.d("ress"," delivered "+a.getDeli_orders());
                            //txtDeliveredOrder.setText(a.getDeli_orders());
                        }
                        if( !(a.getStore_count().contentEquals("null"))){
                            Log.d("ress","store "+a.getStore_count());
                            //txtStoreOrder.setText(a.getStore_count());
                        }


                        }catch (NullPointerException e){

                        }
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<OrderResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("fragres",""+t.getMessage());

                }
            });
```

**Update : Order.java**

```
public class Order {

    String order_count;
    String pending_order;
    String schedule;
    String id_order;
    String reference;
    String deli_orders;
    String store_count;


    public String getOrder_count() {
        return order_count;
    }

    public void setOrder_count(String order_count) {
        this.order_count = order_count;
    }

    public String getPending_order() {
        return pending_order;
    }

    public void setPending_order(String pending_order) {
        this.pending_order = pending_order;
    }

    public String getSchedule() {
        return schedule;
    }

    public void setSchedule(String schedule) {
        this.schedule = schedule;
    }

    public String getId_order() {
        return id_order;
    }

    public void setId_order(String id_order) {
        this.id_order = id_order;
    }

    public String getReference() {
        return reference;
    }

    public void setReference(String reference) {
        this.reference = reference;
    }

    public String getDeli_orders() {
        return deli_orders;
    }

    public void setDeli_orders(String deli_orders) {
        this.deli_orders = deli_orders;
    }

    public String getStore_count() {
        return store_count;
    }

    public void setStore_count(String store_count) {
        this.store_count = store_count;
    }



}
```

Logcat

[image]

when i check null inside for loop,it's display only first value (num 3)

i want to get :

1st value from 1 data set,2 nd value from 2nd data set,3rd and 4th value from 3 data set,5th value from 4th data set,6th value from 5th data set

Comment: are you using POJO to parsing the json results ?

Comment: No.just data model

Comment: ok, so you can check the null by running a for loop in the response. And remove the null values from it

Comment: i have updated my question.when i check null ,it's display only first value (no3).

Comment: add your data model in the question

Comment: is the above said POSTMAN response is the complete response you are getting ? There is something missing in your question..

Comment: i have updated my question.POSTMAN response is the complete response i got.

Comment: okay, in your data array, you are getting different json objects (though this array should consists of same type data). That's where you met error

Comment: an array should contain (multiple) entries of same set data like "data": [
        {
            "a": "some_value",
   "b": "some_value"
        },
        {
            "a": "some_value",
   "b": "some_value"
        }
    ] <see the sets in {}>

Comment: but your array looks like   "data": [
   {
    "a": "some_value",
   },
   {
    "b": "some_value"
   }
  ]

Comment: I think now you get an idea whats i'm saying. If you run a loop like in your code it'll check all the if conditions data that are not presented to the loop at each run. thats why you are getting results like in your log data. for first run of your loop you get 1 0 0 0 0 0, for second you get 0 1 0 0 0 0  for third 0 0 1 0 0 0 and so on.